# Is it possible to link an external style sheet in a particular component??(not globally)

Tags: html, angular, angular6, stylesheet

I want 2 components in an angular 6 application

I wish first component to use bootstrap min.css file , and the other not

how can i implement this

Comment: Are you using SCSS for your component?
If yes use `@import "bootstrap.css";` Here you need to give correct path for bootstrap.css file.

Comment: No iam not using SCSS files..

Comment: I think you could add the path to the bootstrap min file to the stylesUrls: [] array in the component.

Comment: styleUrls: ['./login.component.css','src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css']

Comment: this give me errors...         ERROR in ./src/app/authentication/login-component/login/login.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'

Comment: can you show me an example

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) for that.

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom
})
```

Using shadow dom ensures that your base project styling will not be applied.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/aos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"> 

    i want to disable only  bootsrap.css file